# readString is throwing TypeError: malformed UTF-8

Tags: firefox-addon, jsctypes

This function returns a `ctypes.unsigned_char.array()` and I do read string on it. It is getting the titles of windows. The problem is sometimes it throws TypeError.

```
try {
    console.error('straight readString on XWindowGetProperty data:', rez_GP.data.readString());
} catch (ex) {
    console.error('ex on straight readString:', ex);
}
```

Please notice the `rez_GP.data.readString()`

For example this instance: `TypeError: malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset 48`. In this situation the window title is `Editing js-macosx/bootstrap.js at base-template · Noitidart/js-macosx - Mozilla Firefox` The 48th offset is that dot chracter you see, it's chracter code is `183`. How to do `readString()` on this buffer without getting this error?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use the XA_WM_NAME atom?

Comment: I used the `WS_NAME` atom. Which is also used by `XGetWMName` convenience function, I run into that readString issue with `XGetWMName` too.

Answer (score 1):

`readString` expects a utf-8 encoded string. This is true for strings returned by `_NET_WM_NAME`, but not for `WM_NAME`.

Comment: Ah thank you very much for that insight, I didn't know that about readString. So what would i do for non utf-8 encoded, how to read those? Thanks for the extra insight about those atoms :)

Comment: Use the `_NET_WM_NAME` atom.

Comment: Thanks @paa but its not about this specifically, I just used it as an example. But `_NET_WM_NAME` returns blank for lots of windows while `WM_NAME` does not so i have to use the convenience function of `XGetWMName` for that situation.

Comment: A note on mdn says "Note: The source C string is assumed to be UTF-8, and is assumed to be null terminated. If you need to convert a string that doesn't meet these requirements, you'll need to do it yourself." Saying I ave to do it myself. Do you know any ways in that way?

Comment: Hey @paa I posted another solution here, I figured out a way to read it, could you please comment on it, like if its a good way or there can be some issues with it please.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to read the string propertly even ifs not utf-8, but im not sure if its he best way or the recommended way. This works though, i have to cast it to `unsigned_char` (must be this, so not `char` or `jschar`) then do `fromCharCode`:

```
function readAsChar8ThenAsChar16(stringPtr, known_len, jschar) {
    // when reading as jschar it assumes max length of 500

    // stringPtr is either char or jschar, if you know its jschar for sure, pass 2nd arg as true
    // if known_len is passed, then assumption is not made, at the known_len position in array we will see a null char
    // i tried getting known_len from stringPtr but its not possible, it has be known, i tried this:
        //"stringPtr.contents.toString()" "95"
        //"stringPtr.toString()" "ctypes.unsigned_char.ptr(ctypes.UInt64("0x7f73d5c87650"))"
        // so as we see neither of these is 77, this is for the example of "_scratchpad/EnTeHandle.js at master · Noitidart/_scratchpad - Mozilla Firefox"

    // tries to do read string on stringPtr, if it fails then it falls to read as jschar

    var readJSCharString = function() {
        var assumption_max_len = known_len ? known_len : 500;
        var ptrAsArr = ctypes.cast(stringPtr, ctypes.unsigned_char.array(assumption_max_len).ptr).contents; // MUST cast to unsigned char (not ctypes.jschar, or ctypes.char) as otherwise i dont get foreign characters, as they are got as negative values, and i should read till i find a 0 which is null terminator which will have unsigned_char code of 0 // can test this by reading a string like this: "_scratchpad/EnTeHandle.js at master · Noitidart/_scratchpad - Mozilla Firefox" at js array position 36 (so 37 if count from 1), we see 183, and at 77 we see char code of 0 IF casted to unsigned_char, if casted to char we see -73 at pos 36 but pos 77 still 0, if casted to jschar we see chineese characters in all spots expect spaces even null terminator is a chineese character
        console.info('ptrAsArr.length:', ptrAsArr.length);
        //console.log('debug-msg :: dataCasted:', dataCasted, uneval(dataCasted), dataCasted.toString());
        var charCode = [];
        var fromCharCode = []
        for (var i=0; i<ptrAsArr.length; i++) { //if known_len is correct, then will not hit null terminator so like in example of "_scratchpad/EnTeHandle.js at master · Noitidart/_scratchpad - Mozilla Firefox" if you pass length of 77, then null term will not get hit by this loop as null term is at pos 77 and we go till `< known_len`
            var thisUnsignedCharCode = ptrAsArr.addressOfElement(i).contents;
            if (thisUnsignedCharCode == 0) {
                // reached null terminator, break
                console.log('reached null terminator, at pos: ', i);
                break;
            }
            charCode.push(thisUnsignedCharCode);
            fromCharCode.push(String.fromCharCode(thisUnsignedCharCode));
        }
        console.info('charCode:', charCode);
        console.info('fromCharCode:', fromCharCode);
        var char16_val = fromCharCode.join('');
        console.info('char16_val:', char16_val);
        return char16_val;
    }

    if (!jschar) {
        try {
            var char8_val = stringPtr.readString();
            console.info('stringPtr.readString():', char8_val);
            return char8_val;
        } catch (ex if ex.message.indexOf('malformed UTF-8 character sequence at offset ') == 0) {
            console.warn('ex of offset utf8 read error when trying to do readString so using alternative method, ex:', ex);
            return readJSCharString();
        }
    } else {
        return readJSCharString();
    }
}
```